# Basic Auth header not sent (Swagger)

Tags: swagger-2.0, swagger-editor

I have a basic auth secured API but after filling in the authentication credentials, it does not apply to request header. I saw"ERROR Server not found or an error occurred " at swagger editor and "401 Unauthorized" on fiddler.

User Name and Pwd : odata and qtkr47PTM3pmzLyEHNrW4DXhhgyjMfM3CKUZfXdn0tk=

Here is my swagger json

```
{
"swagger": "2.0",
"info": {
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "title": "Basic Auth Example",
    "description": "An example for how to use Basic Auth with Swagger.\nServer code is available [here](http://navm3.cloudapp.net:90/nav/odata). It's running on NAVM3.\n\n**You can use below User Name and Password for test.**\n* User Name: `ODATA`\n* Password: `qtkr47PTM3pmzLyEHNrW4DXhhgyjMfM3CKUZfXdn0tk=`\n"
},
"host": "navm3.cloudapp.net:90",
"basePath": "/nav/odata",
"schemes": [
    "http"
],
"securityDefinitions": {
    "basicAuth": {
        "type": "basic",
        "description": "HTTP Basic Authentication. Works over `HTTP` and `HTTPS`"
    }
},
"paths": {
    "/": {
        "get": {
            "security": [
                {
                    "basicAuth": []
                }
            ],
            "responses": {
                "200": {
                    "description": "Will send `Authenticated` if authentication is succesful, otherwise it will send `Unauthorized`"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

i had the same problem, but the problem was in nodeJS back-end.

If you are using NodeJS, probably the problem it is with CORS. You should enable CORS in NodeJS with Express and everything will work.

To enable the CORS in nodeJS you can add the below code, before of the routes.

```
var app = express();

app.use(function(req, res, next) {

    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, UPDATE, DELETE, OPTIONS');

    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization');

    next();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

try to replace the following part:

```
"securityDefinitions": {
    "basicAuth": {
        "type": "basic",
        "description": "HTTP Basic Authentication. Works over `HTTP` and `HTTPS`"
    }
},
```

with the following

```
"securityDefinitions": {
    "basicAuth": {
        "type": "http",
        "scheme": "basic"
    }
},
```

keeping the rest as is
here is the reference https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/basic-authentication/